# 400 Bad Request error when when moving application from local to web server

Tags: javascript, python, web-hosting

I have a pyramid application that runs perfectly on a local server, but when I move it over to a web server (Dreamhost), I get the following error:

```
400 Bad Request:
Bad request (GET and HEAD requests may not contain a request body)
```

The code in question is the following ajax in Javascript:

```
function summary_ajax(sName){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "summary",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'ccg_name': sName,
            },
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {

                //alert("In ajax success function")   <-----------  This never executes
                lValues = data.lValues;
                lLabels = data.lLabels;
            }, 
        });
    };
    return (lValues, lLabels);
```

And is handled in views.py:

```
@view_config(route_name="ccg_map_summary_ajax",renderer="json")
def ccg_map_summary_ajax(self):


    sCCG = self.request.POST.get('ccg_name')

    fData = open('pyramidapp/static/view_specific_js/ajax_summary_data.js')
    dData = json.load(fData)

    lLabels = dData[sCCG].keys()
    lValues = dData[sCCG].values()


    return {
        'lLabels' : lLabels,
        'lValues' : lValues,
        }
```

I did some testing by placing `alert()` functions (its slow, because the server only reloads the script every so many minutes), and everything executes fine except for alerts in the ajax call.  So it seems that either the post fails, or something goes wrong in the view.  Any ideas?

So is there something in this code that works in my local server (in Pyramid) but breaks down in the web server (Dreamhost)?
The file structure is the same in the local and web server.  I don't see why it shouldn't, but will fData still open the file for reading?

Comment: If you can't access the logs in the servers, good luck. If the problem is an unhandled exception, you'll may be able to catch it, and display its message, just drop a big try-except around your request handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else out there, I found the problem:

The path I specified above was a relative path that worked on my system but not on the server because the working directories are obviously different.  So instead of using a relative path, I just changed the script to have the correct absolute path.

To find the current working directory path, just enter `pwd` into terminal.